# FontAwsome icon liabrary is very limited

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, font-awesome

I'm using fontawesome extension for Yii, but it seems that only a fraction of the full library is available. Is there a way to get the ones I'm missing and add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the assets folder of the extension with the latest css and font files. It will be in

```
protected->
  extensions ->
   EFontAwesome -> 
     Assets ->
```

The latest font awesome files will be available at
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/